# Can Mediawiki show different users different versions of a page?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a mediawiki extension that can distinguish between page versions?

I would like to run mediawiki for 3 kinds of user-rights:

- editors (who can edit a page and see its latest version)
- gatekeepers
  (who can define which versions are public)
- readers (who see only the
  latest version of a page)

So e.g. a use case would be:

Precondition: Page1 has 3 versions: Version1, Version2, Version3 (Version3 is the most recent).
Version1 has the attribute "public", but Version2 and Version3 do not.

Use Case 1. A reader requests Page1.  The system shows Version1.

Use case 2. An editor requests Page1.  The system shows Version3.

User case 3. A gatekeeper gives Version3 the "public" attribute.  A reader requests Page1.  The system shows Version3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Approved Revs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Approved_Revs) is a MediaWiki extension that should do what you describe. Users with the `approverevisions` permission (i.e. gatekeepers) can approve revisions of a page that will be shown by default, and users with the `viewlinktolatest` permission (similar to editors) sees a link to the latest (not necessarily approved) revision.

If you want to be able to further make further configurations, you can use the [Flagged Revisions extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlaggedRevs), which is used on a number of Wikimedia projects. It uses the reviewer user right, which corresponds to gatekeeper, to approve individual edits. Take a look at [Help:Extension:FlaggedRevs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:FlaggedRevs) for help using the extension and [the Flagged Revisions page](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Flagged_Revisions) on Meta-Wiki for how the extension is used on Wikipedia.